# OpenSSL ecc function with macos xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, openssl

I am trying to use the function EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1) present in openssl. However, when I compile, I get the following error:

```
    undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name", referenced from:
      CKey::CKey() in bitcoin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have been hinted that macos openssl is not compile with the ECC extensions. Is the problem? If so, how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the OpenSSL library that comes with MacOS SDK, then it should automatically have 64-bit support built in.

Looking at [the first hit on Google](https://github.com/laanwj/bitcoin-qt/issues/1), I'm wondering if you are just not including the correct library in your XCode project.  Did you get `-lcrypto` into the project settings, or forget to add `libCrypto.dylib` to your list of libraries in the project?

On my SnowLeopard (10.6) machine, I see the symbols are defined in `libCrypto`:

```
[/usr/lib]:; nm -arch x86_64 libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib | egrep -i new_by_curve
00000000000a4ac0 T _EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name
00000000000ab540 T _EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name
```

Comment: thanks: added -L/usr/lib -lcrypto to "Other Linker Flags build setting" and it worked.